# Как в JSP вывести одну из трех таблиц

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp

Подскажите, а то уже всю голову сломал! Задача: У меня есть три таблицы, с помощью "поля со списком"  я должен выбрать одну из них и в цикле вывести:

```
<select  name="select" size="1">
        <option selected value="Table1">Вариант1</option>
        <option value="Table2">Вариант2</option>
        <option value="Table3">Вариант3</option>
</select>
```

а вот цикл:

```
<c:forEach var="part" items="${Table1}">
    <tr>
        <td>${part.name}</td>
        <td>${part.need}/></td>
        <td>${part.count}</td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

как можно заменить значение items в зависимости от select'a?

Comment: Ну по логике, если это MVC, value вашего select (Table1, Table2 или Table3) должно уйти на контроллер, где решится какой из списков отдать. Если вам такое подходит, скажите, я набросаю примерный код

Comment: Буду премного благодарен, если поможете! За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Никак нельзя, раетайм разный.

Comment: Никак нельзя, раетайм разный.

Comment: @aron4ik, еще актуально ?